# Best way to deal with React & Stripe sign up flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

I am building an application that requires a sign up flow for bar owners so we can collect necessary information about their location. For example: address, bar hours, website, phone number, etc.

Once that's complete, we need to onboard the bar with our Stripe platform via connected accounts. In doing so, Stripe requires users get redirected to a Stripe webpage to complete the onboarding process.

The issue that I'm running into is as follows: bar owner fills in necessary information on form, once completed they get redirected to Stripe's onboarding url. When they get redirected, all the information from the form is lost.

Is there a way to retain the form's state so when Stripe returns to our form after completion, it keeps all the previously filled out fields?

I might be missing something here. Please let me know if you can think of a better process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really related to Stripe, but rather a general problem of losing unsaved information when redirecting. You should commit those fields to your database record for your user and hydrate on return, or alternately use some sort of local persistence (eg see this example with `formik-persist` [1]).

You can retrieve the user from a cookie etc when they return to load the data and hydrate the form, or include a static user id in the `return_url` you supply when creating the onboarding link [2].

[1] https://egghead.io/lessons/react-persist-form-data-in-react-and-formik-with-formik-persist
[2] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/connect-onboarding#return_url